# jQuery satisfied 'if' not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am playing with some interactive menus, and currently have a hidden menu, that when a button is pressed appears in from the right and shifts the whole content over. A bit like the mobile facebook app does. To determine whether the button should slide the menu out or put it back in i use the javascript if statement, however only the else will run when the if condition is not satisfied, the if wont run if the statement is satisfied.

```
var height = $(window).height(),
    width = $(window).width(),
    sideright = $("#sidemenu").outerWidth();
    sidepos = parseInt($("#sidemenu").css( "right" ));

    $("#sidemenu").css("right", - sideright);

    $(".menubutton").click( function() {
        alert(sidepos);

    if(sidepos == '0') {    
        $("#sidemenu").css("right", - sideright);
        $("#content").css("left", "0" );
    }

    else{
        $("#sidemenu").css("right", "0");
        $("#content").css("left", - sideright);
    }

    alert(sidepos);
});
```

The alerts are for test purposes so i can see what the variable is being read as before a function is executed.

It would appear that after the menu has been shifted, the variable that reads the menus right position isn't changing as it should.

I have a sample script set up here http://jsfiddle.net/Ccxs6/

Many Thanks

Comment: Why `parseInt()`? `right:auto` will never be parsed to an integer, your if condition will never be satisfied

Comment: That was just so everything was in pure numerical form to get rid of the 'px' for the if condition, possibly not necessary but just a fail safe.

Comment: BTW, should be a comma here: `.outerWidth(), <<-`

Comment: But sidepos will return `auto`, and the `if` condition fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is updated fiddle with solution.

```
$("#button").click( function() {
    var sidepos = parseInt($("#sidemenu").css( "right" ));
    alert(sidepos);

if(sidepos == '0') {    

    $("#sidemenu").css("right", - sideright);
    $("#content").css("left", "0" );
}

else{

    $("#sidemenu").css("right", "0");
    $("#content").css("left", - sideright);
}

    alert(sidepos);

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ccxs6/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `sidepos` to `-sideright` anyway, so just use that, and in the condition, check for a number not a string, and once clicked, the variable must be updated, otherwise the condition will always give the same result :

```
var height = $(window).height(),
    width = $(window).width(),
    sideright = $("#sidemenu").outerWidth(),
    sidepos = -sideright;

$("#sidemenu").css("right", -sideright);

$("#button").click(function () {
    if (sidepos === 0) {
        $("#sidemenu").css("right", -sideright);
        $("#content").css("left", "0");
    } else {
        $("#sidemenu").css("right", "0");
        $("#content").css("left", -sideright);
    }
    sidepos = parseInt($("#sidemenu").css("right"),10);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ccxs6/3/)